what is the reason tablespace not showing in dba_tablepsaces after being created succefully
I have executed the below command , and I can find in in the directory , its there. But quering `select * from dba_tablespaces' I cannot find it. I am trying to create a new schema on this tablespace but throwing error tablessoace doesn't exist. what is my mistake ?
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE ESC_SCHEMA_DATA DATAFILE  '/datafiles/CDB1/O19/ESC_SCHEMA_DATA.DBF' SIZE 536870912000 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1073741824 MAXSIZE 33554431M LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT  NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO


Have a look in the CDB_ views. You probably created the tablespace in a pluggable database (PDB), thereafter you queried the DBA_ views from the root-container. There you will only find the tablespaces for the CDB.
If you navigate to the PDB, you can ask the DBA_ view or the CDB_ view. The tablespace should be listed. You can also go to the root container and ask the CDB_ views. All tablespaces in your multitenant database will be listed.
Login to the root-container (CDB)
sqlplus sys/Welcome_#1@localhost/FREE as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Dec 4 22:22:45 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

sys@FREE>  col file_name for a100
sys@FREE> select file_name from cdb_data_files;

FILE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/undotbs01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/system01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/sysaux01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/system01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/undotbs01.dbf

8 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.30
sys@FREE> select file_name from dba_data_files;

FILE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/undotbs01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/system01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/sysaux01.dbf

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
sys@FREE>

Login to the pluggable database (PDB):
sqlplus sys/Welcome_#1@localhost/FREEPDB1 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Dec 4 22:24:04 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

sys@FREEPDB1> select file_name from dba_data_files;

FILE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/sysaux01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/system01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/undotbs01.dbf

Elapsed: 00:00:00.08
sys@FREEPDB1> select file_name from cdb_data_files;

FILE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/sysaux01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/users01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/system01.dbf
/opt/oracle/oradata/FREE/FREEPDB1/undotbs01.dbf

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10

Best of luck!

you are right , its in the plugable. I have to drop the tablespace then create it in the container ? I should run this   alter session set container = O19 then create the tablespace right ?

It depends on your requirements , but yes that is the right way to create a tablespace alter session set container = YOUR_PDB or YOUR_CDB and then create statement.
